# Large string (from BeautifulSoup) into SQLite table - can not use traditional method

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I hope you can help.

I am currently writing a code to extract historical data for various games on SteamSpy.com. After backing the project on Patreon, you get to view the long history of various metrics for each game. I would like to make comparisons between multiple games, and as such I want to extract the data.

I know from earlier that BeautifulSoup can be very helpful for this task, unfortunately I can not use it in the way I have done earlier. I will describe it in detail below, but the main problem is, that all the relevant data is included inside ONE single tag.

- Example: Dota2
- URL: http://steamspy.com/app/570
- Source code: [*view-source:http://steamspy.com/app/570*](http://view-source:http://steamspy.com/app/570)

**Source code**
Here is the part of the source code, that I am interested in (it is obviously far longer when logged in, and you have access to the historical data).

```
<div class="tab-content no-padding bg-transparent">
<div class="tab-pane active relative" id="tab-sales">
<h2>Owners data:</h2>
<div id="nvd3-sales" class="line-chart" data-area-color="master" data-points="false" data-stroke-width="4">
<svg></svg>
</div>
<script>
var data2sales= [
{
  "key": "Owners",
  "bar": true,
  "values": [
[1489363200000, 97073321, ""],
[1489449600000, 97138657, ""],
[1489536000000, 97126694, ""],
[1489622400000, 98535521, ""],
[1489708800000, 98482905, ""],
[1489795200000, 98496091, ""],
[1489881600000, 98627987, "#2B6A94"],
[1489968000000, 98798351, ""],
[1490054400000, 98936652, ""],
[1490140800000, 99025494, ""],
[1490227200000, 99208644, ""],
[1490313600000, 99163634, ""],
[1490400000000, 99097059, ""],
[1490486400000, 98986347, "#2B6A94"],
[1490572800000, 99005343, ""],
[1490659200000, 99023673, ""],
[1490745600000, 99084059, ""],
[1490832000000, 98988641, ""],
[1490918400000, 99120523, ""],
[1491004800000, 99058884, ""],
[1491091200000, 99206546, "#2B6A94"],
[1491177600000, 99155567, ""] ]},{
  "key" : "Price",
  "values" : [
[1489363200000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489449600000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489536000000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489622400000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489708800000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489795200000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489881600000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1489968000000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490054400000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490140800000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490227200000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490313600000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490400000000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490486400000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490572800000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490659200000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490745600000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490832000000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1490918400000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1491004800000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1491091200000,, "#ffffff" ],
[1491177600000,, "#ffffff" ]] } ];
                          </script>
</div>
```

My ultimate goal is to extract the three values for each row in the code below, inside the `<script>` tag, and only the values that begin in the row after `"values": [`.

Below is the part of my code that takes care of collecting the data, I have tried multiple solutions, but all I have found only suggests that I iterate over the tags in the "soup", and collect the data inside, however, here all my data is placed inside one SINGLE tag. I hope you can help out.

Please also tell me, if I can provide more information, that could be useful.

Cheers!

**Code**
My code (I run it inside a session, since I have to log in before collecting the data, I have removed the log in part):

```
### START ###
import requests
from requests import session
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseURL = "http://steamspy.com/app/"
appNum = "387990"
fullURL = baseURL + appNum

# log-in information to access the full historical data.
payload = {
    'username': 'XXXX',
    'password': 'XXXX',
    'doLogin':    'doLogin'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    #log in on steamSpy
    # q = s.post('https://steamspy.com/login.php', data=payload)
    # print(q.status_code)
    # print(q.history)
    # print(q.url)

    #navigate to the desired webpage
    r = s.get(fullURL)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    ownr = soup.find("div", {"id": "tab-sales"}).find("script").get_text()
    print(ownr)
```

**Output**
And here is my output, which obviously is similar to what is inside the  tag in the source code:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe "C:/Users/nohgjk/Dropbox/Gaming/Project steamSpy/Python/steamSpy - Test/steamSpySoup2.py"

var data2sales= [
{
  "key": "Owners",
  "bar": true,
  "values": [
[1489363200000, 549045, ""],
[1489449600000, 550812, ""],
[1489536000000, 550773, ""],
[1489622400000, 544180, ""],
[1489708800000, 532284, ""],
[1489795200000, 546592, ""],
[1489881600000, 545925, "#2B6A94"],
[1489968000000, 550721, ""],
[1490054400000, 539253, ""],
[1490140800000, 536258, ""],
[1490227200000, 544210, ""],
[1490313600000, 560977, ""],
[1490400000000, 562907, ""],
[1490486400000, 554817, "#2B6A94"],
[1490572800000, 552973, ""],
[1490659200000, 551875, ""],
[1490745600000, 554853, ""],
[1490832000000, 553309, ""],
[1490918400000, 551987, ""],
[1491004800000, 551671, ""],
[1491091200000, 541915, "#2B6A94"],
[1491177600000, 541280, ""] ]},{
  "key" : "Price",
  "values" : [
[1489363200000, 19.99, ""],
[1489449600000, 19.99, ""],
[1489536000000, 19.99, ""],
[1489622400000, 19.99, ""],
[1489708800000, 19.99, ""],
[1489795200000, 19.99, ""],
[1489881600000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1489968000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490054400000, 19.99, ""],
[1490140800000, 19.99, ""],
[1490227200000, 19.99, ""],
[1490313600000, 19.99, ""],
[1490400000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490486400000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1490572800000, 19.99, ""],
[1490659200000, 19.99, ""],
[1490745600000, 19.99, ""],
[1490832000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490918400000, 19.99, ""],
[1491004800000, 19.99, ""],
[1491091200000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1491177600000, 19.99, ""]] } ];


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used your example on this one. 
Use `regex` to find all text between squared brackets.

Like this:

```
ownr = soup.find("div", {"id": "tab-sales"}).find("script").get_text()

some_data = []

matches = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', ownr)
for match in matches:
    some_data.append(match.split(','))

owners, price = zip(*[iter(some_data)] * (len(some_data) / 2))
```

Which outputs (Pre-edit):

```
[u'1489363200000', u' 97073321', u' ""']
[u'1489449600000', u' 97138657', u' ""']
[u'1489536000000', u' 97126694', u' ""']
[u'1489622400000', u' 98535521', u' ""']
[u'1489708800000', u' 98482905', u' ""']
[u'1489795200000', u' 98496091', u' ""']
[u'1489881600000', u' 98627987', u' "#2B6A94"']
....
```

Find more about regex [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant mate, that is exactely what I wanted. It works fine when I import regex as re.

Comment: I've updated my code per your last request to split into Owners/Price. @user3494191

Comment: When running your code, I get the following error code: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nohgjk/Dropbox/Gaming/Project steamSpy/Python/steamSpy - Test/steamSpySoup5.py", line 71, in <module>
    owners, price = zip(*[iter(some_data)] * (len(some_data) / 2))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` @Zroq

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a task for regex.

```
lists = re.findall(pattern=r"([0-9]{13},.*, \".*\")", string=ownr)
lists
```

Output:

```
['1489363200000, 97073321, ""',
 '1489449600000, 97138657, ""',
 '1489536000000, 97126694, ""',
 '1489622400000, 98535521, ""',
 '1489708800000, 98482905, ""',
 '1489795200000, 98496091, ""',
 '1489881600000, 98627987, "#2B6A94"',
 '1489968000000, 98798351, ""',
 '1490054400000, 98936652, ""',
 '1490140800000, 99025494, ""',
 '1490227200000, 99208644, ""',
 '1490313600000, 99163634, ""',
 '1490400000000, 99097059, ""',
 '1490486400000, 98986347, "#2B6A94"',
 '1490572800000, 99005343, ""',
 '1490659200000, 99023673, ""',
 '1490745600000, 99084059, ""',
 '1490832000000, 98988641, ""',
 '1490918400000, 99120523, ""',
 '1491004800000, 99058884, ""',
 '1491091200000, 99206546, "#2B6A94"',
 '1491177600000, 99155567, ""',
 '1489363200000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489449600000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489536000000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489622400000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489708800000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489795200000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489881600000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1489968000000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490054400000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490140800000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490227200000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490313600000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490400000000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490486400000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490572800000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490659200000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490745600000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490832000000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1490918400000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1491004800000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1491091200000,, "#ffffff"',
 '1491177600000,, "#ffffff"']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it is indeed the solution. I have already marked @Zrog's answer as accepted, but appreciate that you took the time to answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried parsing your code's output.

```
data = '''
var data2sales= [
{
  "key": "Owners",
  "bar": true,
  "values": [
[1489363200000, 549045, ""],
[1489449600000, 550812, ""],
[1489536000000, 550773, ""],
[1489622400000, 544180, ""],
[1489708800000, 532284, ""],
[1489795200000, 546592, ""],
[1489881600000, 545925, "#2B6A94"],
[1489968000000, 550721, ""],
[1490054400000, 539253, ""],
[1490140800000, 536258, ""],
[1490227200000, 544210, ""],
[1490313600000, 560977, ""],
[1490400000000, 562907, ""],
[1490486400000, 554817, "#2B6A94"],
[1490572800000, 552973, ""],
[1490659200000, 551875, ""],
[1490745600000, 554853, ""],
[1490832000000, 553309, ""],
[1490918400000, 551987, ""],
[1491004800000, 551671, ""],
[1491091200000, 541915, "#2B6A94"],
[1491177600000, 541280, ""] ]},{
  "key" : "Price",
  "values" : [
[1489363200000, 19.99, ""],
[1489449600000, 19.99, ""],
[1489536000000, 19.99, ""],
[1489622400000, 19.99, ""],
[1489708800000, 19.99, ""],
[1489795200000, 19.99, ""],
[1489881600000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1489968000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490054400000, 19.99, ""],
[1490140800000, 19.99, ""],
[1490227200000, 19.99, ""],
[1490313600000, 19.99, ""],
[1490400000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490486400000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1490572800000, 19.99, ""],
[1490659200000, 19.99, ""],
[1490745600000, 19.99, ""],
[1490832000000, 19.99, ""],
[1490918400000, 19.99, ""],
[1491004800000, 19.99, ""],
[1491091200000, 19.99, "#2B6A94"],
[1491177600000, 19.99, ""]] } ];
'''
```

using this code.

```
import json
json_data = data.split('=')[1].split(';')[0]
data_dict = json.loads(json_data)
print(data_dict[0]['key'])
```

Now data_dict is a python dictionary.

Comment: That seems like it could be a superior solution, I will look into this later. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It works very well, and in the end, I think I will chose this solution, I had totally forgotten about using JSON for this type of task. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a problem. When running the code after logging in, some places, the third "column" is filled with a very long string (related to Steam sales i guess). For instance, in your output example, the `"#2B6A94"` is replaced by `"http://store.steampowered.com/news/20987/"` or `"Oh…Sir!!"` or even `"Shadow Warrior 2 25% Off + \'The Way of the Wang\' DLC"`.   - Also there are now 5 "columns" instead of 3, but I dont suspect that this has anything to do with it. Can you help me with a way to fix this? I really like the JSON approach otherwise!

Comment: What do you want to do when the third column has a long string?

Comment: I am only interested in the data in the two first "columns". So ultimately, I dont want to do anything with the last columns in each row. I have tried with some .replace code, but it does not help, and also risks ruining the structure in the JSON. @RaviKumar

Comment: you can iterate over your dictionary and use list slicing to keep only first 2 values of each list.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more explicitly how to do that? :) I am still very new to Python in general. If i try and iterate over the data, it will just iterate over every single character, since it does not recognize the "lines" before it has been "converted" into JSON format. At lease that is my guess.

Comment: Do all your processing after `data` is converted into `data_dict`. eg. iterate over `data_dict[0]['values']` use list slicing to get only first 2 columns and maybe create a new dictionary.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately that is already what I am doing, the error occurs when trying to "convert" the `json_data` into JSON with our code: `data_dict = json.loads(json_data)`. It seems that the problem is due to some of the material in the columns after you log in to the site, and I have tried to write in the comment earlier.

Comment: *** I get the following error *** `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/steamSpyJSON.py", line 60, in <module>
    data_dict = json.loads(json_data)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 624 column 64 (char 24554)`

Comment: Which escape character is this at line 624 column 64?

Comment: It was the `\ ` character. I managed to get it running with some `.replace` commands. Thanks for the help.